# Nodejs closure issue

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, ioredis

I am using express-session with RedisStore in my node web application.

*NodeJs version: 4.2.4
JS: Es6*

*"express": "^4.13.3",
"express-session": "https://github.com/echorohit/session/tarball/1d22749aa46280a24a4ee3a993ba0772e6e1e2df",
"ioredis": "^1.13.0",
"connect-redis": "^3.0.1",*

I observed that once in a while the session are getting mixed up between users. I was using newrelic insights for logging some metrics so I used that to debug the issue also.

Here are my findings.

*code snippet from store.js of express-session*

```
 Store.prototype.regenerate = function(req, fn){
     var self = this;
     //CHECKPOINT 1
     log.addNewRelicCustomParameter("CHECKPOINT1",req.sessionID);
     this.destroy(req.sessionID, function(err){
        //CHECKPOINT 2
        log.addNewRelicCustomParameter("CHECKPOINT2",req.sessionID);
        self.generate(req, fn);
        fn(err);
     });
};
```

At **CHECKPOINT 1.** The req.sessionID was correct but strangely at **CHECKPOINT 2.** the req.sessionID was printed for other request being  concurrently executed in new relic logs.

I am sure this is the cause of session mixup. But not able to debug further to find root cause of it. Please help me with tips how to get to the root cause of problem. Not sure if this is really closure scope problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is actually no problem!

If you set a breakpoint at each of your checkpoints, it is to be expected that sometimes the `req.sessionID` will differ between the breakpoints, since the second breakpoint is inside an asynchronous callback.

Comment: Its not break point issue. because this data is given by newrelic insights ,at checkpoint 1 the value was session1 and at checkpoint 2 the value was session2. I am here assuming that newrelic is detecting one request execution flow correctly so able to detect the anomaly. here is insight sample query to detect issue SELECT * FROM Transaction  WHERE  `checkpoint1`!=`checkpoint2`